# How the presence of a critical level is related to the existence of a critical point?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand one of the most important concept in Calculs of Variations. I have often heard that the change of topology implies the existence of a critical point. In this context, critical (subcritical) levels have a fundamental role. I don't know something more.

Could anyone please explain me (also intuitively) how critical levels are related to critical points of a functional? What is a critical level of minimax type?

Some examples or references will be appreciated, too. Thank you in advance!